# How to solve Insufficient Permission (to submit GPU work from background) (IOAF code 6)?

Tags: ios, xcode, metal

I have developed an app that uses Metal performance shaders to compute the machine learning prediction from a TensorFlow trained model. The app works fine in foreground but in background I get the error:

"Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Insufficient Permission (to submit GPU work from background) (IOAF code 6)"

How do we enable GPU processing in background mode?

Answer (score 2):

This currently isn't possible. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Device/Device.html):

> A Metal app cannot execute Metal commands in the background [...]

Comment: Thanks @warrenm what if I convert the implementation to a BNNS? would that work in the background?

Comment: I don't think BNNS has the same restriction, being CPU-based.

Comment: This reply is years later, but something interesting I discovered recently is that if you use a CoreML model (or higher level abstraction like the Vision Framework) in the background, you will get this error as well on devices with an A11 or older CPU because they are computed using Metal. But if you use a device with an A12 or higher CPU which allows access to the neural engine, they can run in the background fine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with warrenm about that and i added that to avoid most IOAF Errors try not to do heavy or complex calculations like sorting data or such within the renderer try use External Loops to call this calculations. 
please check https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html